# Setting Tethering/hotspot for Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, tethering

I use this code to activate or deactivate the tethering hotspot so other devices can use the Internet data of my device. 
It used to work well but it is not working anymore for Nougat, do you have any hint?
thanks.

This is the code I use:

```
  private boolean ActivateTethering(boolean bEstate) 
  {  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

     Method[] methods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
     for(Method method : methods) 
     {  if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) 
        {  try 
           {  if(bEstate == true)
              {  wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false); //Turning off wifi because tethering requires wifi to be off
                 method.invoke(wifiManager, null, true); //Activating tethering
                 return true;
              }
              else
              {  method.invoke(wifiManager, null, false); //Deactivating tethering
                 return true;
              }
           }
           catch(Exception e) 
           {  return false;
           }           
         }
     }

     //Error setWifiApEnabled not found 
     return false;
 }
```

I get the error **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
try {
    Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
    method.invoke(wifiManager, null, true); // true to enable, false to disable
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // WiFi tethering is blocked.
}
```

Change it for your needs
It works on my S7 Edge while `getDeclaredMethods();` way does not.